# Linux server (debian) : TTY 6.5GiB

Tags: linux, tty

I'm running a VPS which has 10GiB.

Today, it was almost full. I noticed it when i was not able to update/upgrade.

`ncdu` command shows me that `/dev/tty10` is taking 6.5 GiB.

How can i reduce it ? 
Can i delete it ?

`ls -l | grep tty` in `/dev` gives me that :

`crw------- 1 root tty      5,   1 juil. 22  2014 console
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty      5,   0 août   2 18:33 tty
crw------- 1 root tty      4,   0 mars   4  2011 tty0
crw-rw---- 1 root tty      4,   1 août   2 12:09 tty1
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  6990769469 août   2 18:43 tty10
crw-rw---- 1 root tty      4,   2 août   2 12:09 tty2
crw-rw---- 1 root tty      4,   3 août   2 12:09 tty3
crw-rw---- 1 root tty      4,   4 août   2 12:09 tty4
crw-rw---- 1 root tty      4,   5 août   2 12:09 tty5
crw-rw---- 1 root tty      4,   6 août   2 12:09 tty6
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,   0 nov.  30  2014 ttyp0
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,   1 nov.  30  2014 ttyp1
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,   2 nov.  30  2014 ttyp2
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,   3 nov.  30  2014 ttyp3
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,   4 nov.  30  2014 ttyp4
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,   5 nov.  30  2014 ttyp5
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,   6 nov.  30  2014 ttyp6
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,   7 nov.  30  2014 ttyp7
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,   8 nov.  30  2014 ttyp8
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,   9 nov.  30  2014 ttyp9
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,  10 nov.  30  2014 ttypa
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,  11 nov.  30  2014 ttypb
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,  12 nov.  30  2014 ttypc
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,  13 nov.  30  2014 ttypd
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,  14 nov.  30  2014 ttype
crw-r---wx 1 root root     3,  15 nov.  30  2014 ttypf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remaking `/dev/tty10` seems like the way to go: either you had none to begin with, and something decided to write to that (missing) device, or something removed the name from `/dev`.

If your VPS is using udev, rebooting might just fix that automatically (see for example notes in *[need to rebuild /dev](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/need-to-rebuild-dev-354950/)*).

Comment: I tried to reboot (i should have precise that, sorry). It didn't change anything.

Comment: If something is writing to it (seems likely), it would be nice to stop that process and remake the /dev/tty10 (so it is a *device* like the others).

Comment: I did move it to a .bak file, restarted and then deleted it. Thanks :)